# Problem mounting my iRiver story HD on Ubuntu

Tags: filesystems, mount, devices

I would like to connect my iRiver Story HD to my ubuntu 12.04 machine but as I connect it I get this error:

> Unable to mount Story HD
>
> Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
>   /dev/sdb,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

This is what I get with `dmesg`

```
[58332.932515] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
[58332.933056] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[58332.933132] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[58349.254839] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
[58349.535804] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[58350.535209] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     iriver   Story EB07       0326 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[58350.537099] scsi 7:0:0:1: Direct-Access     iriver   Story SD         0326 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[58350.538773] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[58350.539178] sd 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[58350.548997] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 3243041 512-byte logical blocks: (1.66 GB/1.54 GiB)
[58350.657284] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[58350.657291] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0f 00 00 00
[58350.767369] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[58350.777168] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[58351.004612]  sdb:
[58351.237097] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[58351.503837] FAT-fs (sdb): codepage cp437 not found
[58362.792082] FAT-fs (sdb): codepage cp437 not found
[58388.066212] FAT-fs (sdb): codepage cp437 not found
```

and `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1660 MB, 1660436992 bytes
52 heads, 61 sectors/track, 1022 cylinders, total 3243041 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

**EDIT**

I have already connected it in Windows and it works (just in case somebody assumes it's broken :) )

**EDIT2**

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/sdb

    /dev/sdb: x86 boot sector, mkdosfs boot message display, code offset 0x58,
 OEM-ID " mkdosfs", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, heads 4, sectors 
3243040 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 3161, serial number 0x20, 
label: "Story HD   "
```

Comment: What does `sudo file -s /dev/sdb` show (with the device connected)?

Comment: @Gilles Please check my edit.

Comment: Come to think of it, “codepage cp437 not found” shouldn't be there. What kernel are you running (output of `uname -rv`)? What does `sudo modprobe nls_cp437` show?

Comment: @Gilles The problem was that I was running, kernel `3.2.0-35` BUT i did an upgrade to `3.2.0-36` AND removed `35`without restart. Therefore it didn't see the appropriate modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I was running kernel `3.2.0-35` and I did an upgrade to `3.2.0-36` without a the restart, therefore my kernel was not able to load appropriate modules.

Now after restarting it all works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why it's trying to use 437 at all.

The iriver Story HD itself mounts with these options (both internal FAT as well as SD card FAT):

```
rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp949,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
```

Be a bit careful with what you put on the internal memory. Too long filenames (including directory path) are known to cause the device to brick. It's safer to just put everything on SD card.

Comment: I wanted to put everything on SD card but somehow Ubuntu didn't want to mount it either :/